# Leaflet Magnifying Glass and opacity controls

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, leaflet

I have been looking at Leaflet as an alternative to OpenLayers 3 in the event that I need something more lightweight, but I am running into a problem when trying to integrate some of the generously provided plugins. Specifically, I am trying to get Magnifying Glass (https://github.com/bbecquet/Leaflet.MagnifyingGlass/tree/leaflet-0.7.2) and Opacity Slider (https://github.com/lizardtechblog/Leaflet.OpacityControls) to work together. I am trying to use the DeepZoom tilelayer to make an image viewer for large images.

Do these plugins work together? I can get the buttons to show up, but I get t.onAdd errors when I look at the button click event in the console; the map is not altered at all (no creation/removal of the layer for the magnifying glass).

Similarly, I cannot get the slider (jQuery-UI slider) or the buttons from the Opacity Slider to work. It always come back with an error: $(opacity_slider_div) is not a function.

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It would help if you could provide the code you're working with by means of a JSFiddle (preferably) or at least add relevant parts of the code to your question.

Comment: One difference though between the plugins that you're trying to combine is that OpacityControls is written for Leaflet 0.6.4 and MagnifyingGlass for Leaflet 0.7.2...